# How to make a ldap query to see if 'Identity Management for UNIX' is installed

Tags: unix, active-directory, ldap

I wanted to find out if unix attributes module is installed in AD. One way I could think of is to query for a OID of the schema for unix (for e.g unixHomeDirectory 1.3.1.1.1.1.3). Wanted to know if this is the way to go and how to make such a query.

Thanks
-Aditya

Comment: Was able to get the info by querying the schema, -b"cn=UnixHomeDirectory,cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=test,dc=com"

Answer (score 0):

As updated in the comment was able to get the info.